# defining style in element or in separate tag/file: is there difference

Tags: html, css

Consider the following html-pieces

1.

```
<div class="some-class" style="key: value;">
```

2.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .some-class {color:red;}
</style>
...
<div class="some-class">
```

3.

```
<div class="some-class">
```

with `.some-class {color:red;}` in a separate CSS file. Is there any difference in 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: Your syntax in **2** is incorrect, you mean: `.some-class`. Otherwise you'd be styling a `<some-class>` element.

Comment: Take look on this blog: http://www.cssnewbie.com/inline-in-document-and-linked-css/#.USXv-aVebJY,
It may be usefull to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a difference.

In first case you are using a inline CSS which has the highest priority so it will be applied.

In second case the css is used within HTML then its not a good practice.

In Third case you declare the CSS in external file so it can be used across different html pages and is also easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is: each of these has different priority: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-priority-level/.

And from another point of view - the last one is the best because it can be maintained in the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

The third option, which uses external CSS is considered best practice since your markup does not contain any of the styling information.  It creates a separation of concerns, leaving you with cleaner markup.